# Confusion from Inequality/ Range

Tags: inequality

**Problem:**

Specify the domain and range of the given function.

$f(x)= \dfrac{1}{(x-2)(x-3)}$.

**Solution:**

> The domain consists of all real numbers except $2$ and $3$. To determine the range, set $y=\dfrac{1}{x-2)(x-3)}=\dfrac{1}{x^2-5x+6}$ and solve for $x$. $\; x^2-5x+(6-\dfrac{1}{y})=0$. This has a solution when and only when $b^2-4ac=(-5)^2-4(1)(6-\dfrac{1}{y})=25-24+\dfrac{4}{y}=1+\dfrac{4}{y}\ge0$. This holds if and only if $\dfrac{4}{y}\ge-1$. This holds when $y>0$, and, if $y<0$, when $y\le-4$. Hence the range is $(0,+\infty)\cup(-\infty,-4]$.

**Source:** Schaum's 3000 Solved Problems in Calculus, Chapter.Problem: 5.27

---

When $y>0$, I understand that $\dfrac{4}{y}\ge-1$ holds. From there they say that portion of the range is $(0,+\infty)$. I don't understand why they stop short and say that $\dfrac{4}{y}\ge-1$ holds, instead of isolating $y$ to obtain: $\dfrac{4}{y}\ge-1\Rightarrow4\ge-y \Rightarrow y\ge-4$ and then say the range is $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$. Why is this wrong?

Comment: It seemed everyone misunderstood my question as what happens when multiplying an inequality by a negative, I edited it to make it clearer. Anyways I think I answered it in the comment to amWhy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case when $y<0$, multiplying both sides of the equation $$\frac 4y \geq -1$$ by $y$ changes the direction of the inequality (since we are multiplying both sides of the equation by a negative number). Similarly, multiplying both sides of the equation by $-1$ reverses the direction of the inequality: $$\frac 4y \geq - 1 \iff 4\leq -y \iff -4\geq y \iff y\leq -4$$

Comment: I understand the case when $y<0$, I was having trouble understanding when $y>0$. Notice how when $y<0$ we isolate $y$. However when $y>0$ we state that $\dfrac{4}{y}\ge-1$ holds, without isolating $y$. But, now I think I understand: by initially stating $y>0$ it doesn't make sense to consider $y\ge-4$.

Comment: Exactly, Jesse!

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with inequalities. If you multiply or divide by a negative number then you need to reverse the direction of the inequality. In your example, we have
$$\frac{4}{y} \ge -1 \implies \left\{ 
\begin{array}{ccc} y \ge -4 & \text{if}& y > 0 \\ \\
y \le -4 & \text{if} & y < 0 \end{array}\right.$$
Looking at when this makes sense gives:
$$\frac{4}{y} \ge -1 \iff y \le -4 \ \text{ or } \ y > 0$$

Comment: In the piecewise part, where did the negative sign go?

Comment: Yes: you need ($y \geq -4$ if $y \geq 0) \implies y \geq 0$, and you need $y \leq -4$ if $y \lt 0.$ There's no need to consider the separate region $-4\lt y \lt 0$.

Comment: @Jesse It was a typo. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for spotting the typo.

Answer (score 0):

$$4/y\ge-1\iff4\ge-y$$

Is true only for positive values of $y$. You can multiply an inequality by a positive on both sides and it remains unchanged.

Comment: This statement is incorrect. Let $y=-1$.